# Type conversion with flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to write the following lines of code that are supposed to take an object of type `ClientRect | DOMRect` and convert it into something easier to use.

(`ClientRect` uses `left` and `top`, whereas `DOMRect` uses `x` and `y`)

```
type Bounds = {|
  x: number,
  y: number,
  width: number,
  height: number,
|}

function getLocation() => {
  //ref denote a reference to an HTMLElement
  const rect = ref.current ? ref.current.getBoundingClientRect() : ({ height: 0, width: 0, x: 0, y: 0 }: Bounds);
  if(rect.x!==undefined && rect.y!==undefined) {
    return ({
      x: rect.x,
      y: rect.y,
      width: rect.width,
      height: rect.height,
    }: Bounds);
  } else {
    return ({
      x: rect.left,
      y: rect.top,
      width: rect.width,
      height: rect.height,
    }: Bounds);
  }
}
```

In the previous code, `ref` is a reference to an HTMLElement.

`getBoundingClientRect()` returns an object of type `ClientRect | DOMRect` whose types are defined as such:

```
interface ClientRect {
    bottom: number;
    readonly height: number;
    left: number;
    right: number;
    top: number;
    readonly width: number;
}

interface DOMRect extends DOMRectReadOnly {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

But with this code, I get from flow:

```
Cannot get `rect.y` because property `y` is missing in `ClientRect`
Cannot cast object literal to `Bounds` because property `x` of unknown type [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `x`
```

So how can I create a function that will give me an object of type `Bounds` from the object returned by `getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: If `ref.current` is an `HTMLElement`, then `getBoundingClientRect` should return a `ClientRect` according to https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/be91b251fabd10b2f4e0c62338d0c1b32d39c5a4/lib/dom.js#L1639. Are you using some custom types?

Comment: That's weird... I'm using "flow-bin": "^0.102.0-rc". Maybe it's just my VSCode integration of flow which is using an outdated version. But still, how do you work around this kind of cases aside from this particular situation? When manipulating a A | B object, how can I access the props of A type? Checking `rect.x!==undefined` is not enough?

Comment: Check out the *Disjoint Unions* and *Disjoint unions with exact types* sections of the [Union Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) documentation. Refining between two object types `A` and `B` will depend on if `A` and `B` are exact or inexact and what (if any) properties are shared between the two.

Comment: I read this part, and that's why i'm checking : `rect.x!==undefined` in my code, hoping it would refine the type. But why doesn't it work here? And if that's not the way to do it, I don't see one...

Comment: Ok, I succeeded in the end. I just had to change the test for `rect.top!==undefined` and exchange the condition to make the refining work. Thanks for hinting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot get `rect.y` because property `y` is missing in `ClientRect`
```

its exactly like the error says, you need to add x and y to ClientRect

```
interface ClientRect {
    bottom: number;
    readonly height: number;
    left: number;
    right: number;
    top: number;
    readonly width: number;
    x: number,
    y: number
}
```

Comment: But... The ClientRect type comes from react code, as for getBoundingClientRect... I have no control over it...

Comment: make a new interface extends ClientRect

Comment: But `getBoundingClientRect` will still return an instance of ClientRect and not an instance of my newly created interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` instead of `y` and `left` instead of `x`. I think the `top` has more availability in most of the browsers. Chrome supports `y` and `top` but other browsers may not. This why the `top` is most supported, cross-browser supportive to `y`.